# Save json object to variable from aws s3 storage bucket: Javascript

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm new to AWS and I'm wondering how to get a counter variable from AWS S3 storage bucket and save
it to a variable that has scope beyond the `getOjbect` method.

This is the approach I'm using an this runs in AWS Lambda.

```
  s3.getObject (params, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
          // Handle errors
          console.error (err);
          console.log('things are not working out')
        } else {
          // Read the file content as a string
          const file_content = data.Body.toString ();

        }
      }
```

I've tried assigning the value to a globally scoped variable but I got undefined.

I've also tried different callback and promises around the getObject method but I still get undefined.

I can get data from the getObject method and log it to the console I just can't seem to access it anywhere
else in my program

Is there a way of getting data from an s3 storage bucket and returning it in such a way as to
be able to access it in the rest of my program.

Note I'm using a Lambda function so I cannot use import statements as shown in the documentation.

My `package.json`:

```
{
    "name": "lamda",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "aws-sdk": "^2.1524.0",
        "chrome-aws-lambda": "^10.1.0",
        "puppeteer-core": "^10.4.0",
        "xpath": "^0.0.34",
        "xpath-to-css": "^1.1.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a common problem, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call). If you use aws-sdk/client-s3 (v3), the flow will be much more obvious (it'll just be async functions all around)

Comment: which approach have you tried?

Comment: Well I can see that the data is being logged to the console so I tried using a globally scoped variable that's reasignable and the assigned the global variable the data that I got back from my getObject method. When I logged the variable later and it was undefined. I'm not sure where to begin really. Thanks for not downvoting my question!